# Adding new inputs to component and tracking state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that has a few simple input fields where I am currently tracking the state to eventually be placed into an AJAX call. I also have a button that, on click, will create a new row of input fields (same as the initial inputs).

I am pretty new to React and initially built out a simple function that clones the entire div and appends it to the `.ticket-section` div. I ran into some problems about inputs having the same react-id and it honestly felt like I was fighting the framework a little.

Any recommendations of how to create these new inputs and be able to track the state individually of the new row of inputs? Greatly appreciated in advance.

Here is my component:

```
var AddItem = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {item_name: '', quantity: '', price: ''}
  },
  itemNameChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({item_name: e.target.value});
  },
  quantityChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({quantity: e.target.value});
  },
  priceChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({price: e.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="ticket-section">
        <div className="add-ticket">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <label>Name</label>
              <input id="item-name" type="text" placeholder="xyz item" value={this.state.item_name} onChange={this.itemNameChange} />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Quantity Available</label>
              <input id="quantity" type="number" placeholder="100" value={this.state.quantity} onChange={this.quantityChange} />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Price</label>
              <input id="price" type="number" placeholder="25.00" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.priceChange} />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button className="add-another-item">+ Add another item</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but let me quess, are you looking for something like this?

```
class InputComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){ 
    super(props) 
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
      <input type="text" 
        onChange={this.props.change}/>
     </div>
  }
}

class Widget extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      values: ['']
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(index, e){
    const oldState = this.state.values;
    oldState[index] = e.target.value
    this.setState({values: oldState})
  }

  handleClick(){
    const oldState = this.state.values
    oldState.push('');
    this.setState({values: oldState})
  }
  render(){
    const itemList = this.state.values.map((item, index)=>{
      return  <InputComponent key={index} change={this.handleChange.bind(this, index)}/>
    });
    console.log(this.state.values)
    return <div>
      {itemList}
      <hr/>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  }
}

React.render(<Widget />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[***Fiddle example.***](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/301/) I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this! Not exactly what I needed but definitely something I can reference.